# How to change the IP address on my Ubuntu virtual NIC

Tags: networking, virtualization, webserver, lamp

I have a physical windows system, on which I run VMware Workstation. On a VMware virtual machine I run Ubuntu 12.10 and a LAMP webserver.

Problem:
Now my **local IP address** for my **virtual NIC** (the one Ubuntu is using) has an address of 192.168.159.7, and my home router only issues IP addresses in the range 10.0.0.x. So if I want to port-forward to the virtual NIC, which has a 192.168 address, I cannot, so my LAMP webserver cannot be accessed externally since the router does not know to send the packets on port 80 to the virtual NIC... How do I fix that? The only way, I guess, is to assign a 10.0.0.x ip address to the virtual NIC??

But how do I do that? I tried to do it on the host Windows machine with 'Get my IP address automatically' but it issues a 192.168 address every time...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure the virtual machine's network adapter to be a bridged adapter instead of a NAT adapter. Then Ubuntu will obtain an IP address from the router and not from the Windows host.

One way or another you should see to it that the Ubuntu machine's network adapter has an unchanging IP address. Either configure the interface statically in Ubuntu or create a static address assignment in the DHCP server on the router.

Comment: thank you, it certainly helped.
Why doesn't the VM adapter also get its IP from the Router since is is an adapter on the system much like the Windows adapter? Is it because its not a physical one?

Comment: @DextrousDave: In Bridged mode that's exactly what happens: the VM adapter sees the same LAN as the host's network interface does; it sends out a DHCP request and gets a lease from the router in the same manner as the VMware host does.